# Prove or Disprove that If $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(a_n\right)=0$ then $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{n+1}a_n$ converges.

Tags: calculus

Its obvious that $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{n+1}a_n=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^n\left(-a_n\right)$.
So I wanted to use Alternating series test in order to prove the aforementioned , but couldn't do so.
Also I tried splitting the proof into 4 (an>0,an<0,monotone increasing, monotone decreasing) , but I couldn't figure out what to do in the case of the series not being monotone.
I tried to disprove the statement but all the series I can think about are of the type $\frac{1}{n^k}$ or similar.

Comment: $a_n = (-1)^n/n$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Or start with any diverging series $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } b_n$ such that $b_n \to 0$, and set $a_n = (-1)^n b_n$.

Comment: If this was actually a true statement, then surely one would just call this statement the Alternating Series Test instead

Comment: If this were true then $a_n \to 0$ would be a *sufficient* criterion for the convergence of $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } a_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Try $a_n=(-1)^{n+1}(1/n)$.

Comment: Thanks , I tried $\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{\:n}$ it also works .

Comment: Josef. It does, see also Martin's comment.